# Meaning of "whose auditory effects were achieved by his wireless"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> The other room on the attic floor, smaller still, looked out on the garden.
> It was occupied by a medical student, William Todd, **whose auditory effects
> were achieved by his wireless**, frequently switched on to the classical music
> of the Third Programme. He studied better that way, he claimed.

Dose it mean: his hearing was not damaged by listening to radio and also had been improved by listening?

Source: The Far Cry from Kensington by Muriel Spark

Comment: It means the music came from the radio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auditory effects are sounds. Previously in the story, the narrator described the other tenants and the sounds she heard them make, or in the case of the Carlins, their silence. William Todd's sounds were produced by his wireless (radio).

Comment: I am a nonnative and I did not get the meaning of "auditory effect" and so did not get clearly its meaning so I do not except my question get negative point.

Comment: I did not make the downvote, but my guess is that it is because you did not do any research or thinking. Here is a short story: I could not see four people. Joe coughed, Mary shouted, I could hear Sanjeev whistling. The auditory effects produced by Kima were from her phone. You heard, in various ways, about sounds that I could hear. Hey! Maybe the bit about Kima is about a sound? Let's look up 'auditory' in a dictionary. Here we are: "relating to the sense of hearing". The sounds from Kima were made by her phone.